# It's an algorithm to find the minimum weight between the neighboring vertices of the graph, but why does it time out?

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a weighted solution to the problem. But for several test cases, a timeout of more than 30 seconds occurs. I don't know about the test case. What's the problem? Is "while" the problem? I've been thinking about it for a few days, but I don't know
Can you teach me the revised method?

```
import sys


def compute_weight_diff(w_list, node1, node2):
    return abs(w_list[node1 - 1] - weight_list[node2 - 1])


input_str = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
N, M, K = map(int, input_str.split())

weight_list = []

for _ in range(N):
    weight = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    weight_list.append(weight)

route_list = []

for _ in range(M):
    input_str = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    route = list(map(int, input_str.split()))
    route_list.append(route)

is_over_K = True
total_cost = 0
count = 0

while is_over_K:

    for i in range(M):
        node1 = route_list[i][0]
        node2 = route_list[i][1]
        weight_diff = compute_weight_diff(weight_list, node1, node2)

        if K < weight_diff:
            add_weight = weight_diff - K
            if node1 > node2:
                weight_list[node2 - 1] += add_weight
            else:
                weight_list[node1 - 1] += add_weight
            total_cost += add_weight
        else:
            count += 1

    if count == M:
        is_over_K = False
    else:
        count = 0

print(total_cost)
```

and

- problem

A graph of N vertices and M two-way edges is given.

The apex is numbered from 1 to N. Also, each vertex is weighted. Each time you select a vertex and increase its weight by 1, the cost is equal to 1.

Write a program that calculates the minimum cost required to make the weight difference between all neighboring vertices of the graph less than or equal to K.

- input explanation

On the first line, the number of vertices N, the number of edges M, and the weight difference K are separated by spaces. (2 ≤ N ≤ 50, 1 ≤ M ≤ 200, 1 ≤ K ≤ 100)

A positive integer s is then given across N lines, which means the weight of the i-number vertex. (1 ≤ s ≤ 1,000)

It is then given a positive integer u, v, which means the information of the edges across M lines. This means that there is an edge connecting the U-number vertex and the v-number vertex. In other words, the u-number vertex and the v-number vertex are adjacent.

- test case input

```
5 4 1
10
20
30
40
50
1 2
3 2
3 4
4 5
```

- output

`90`

Answer (score 1):

I went through your code and I believe you are not using a good approach. Your algorithm is to check all edges many times and increment weights of vertices until everything is ok. It's does not always find the minimum cost.

I believe a correct and efficient algorithm for this problem is:

Keep a priority queue with the vertices. The priority criteria is the weight of a vertex (highest weights on top).

Do the following procedure until the queue is empty: take the vertex on top (let's say, `v`), mark it as visited, pop it and look at all neighbors. For a given neighbor `u`, if it's not visited, increment its weight by `min(weight[v] - weight[u] - i) for i in {K, K-1, ..., 0}  such that weight[v] - weight[u] - i >= 0`.

To find `min(weight[v] - weight[u] - i) for i in {K, K-1, ..., 0}  such that weight[v] - weight[u] - i >= 0`, you can use binary search over `{K, K-1, ..., 0}` (time complexity `O(log K)`).

The time complexity is `O(M log K + N log N)`.